# Array Undefined Issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having an issue with the function below that I'm hoping someone might be able to help with.

**The Background:**

The function below is supposed to pull the specified sheet's data in as an array using .getValues() and then the for loop is supposed to be adding the row number to array "StoreRows" if a certain range in the data is found to be empty.

I tried performing this function without arrays but it was not efficient enough and would time out due to sheer volume of data.

**The Error:**

I began getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property "3" from undefined. (line 16, file "Code")" for the line with the if statement.

I added the message box to verify that the array values were pulling in correctly and the function would work.  If I remove the message box, I get the error again.  For some reason, the array is not being recognized within the if statement.

Please help, it would be greatly appreciated!!

Thanks,

Joe

```
function Test()
{
  var SS = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Sheet = SS.getSheets()[0];
  var LastRow = Sheet.getLastRow();
  var Data = Sheet.getRange("A2" + ":" + "T" + LastRow).getValues();
  var ARow = 0;

  var StoreRows = new Array();
  var ArrayRow = 0;


  for(ARow = 0; ARow < LastRow; ARow++)
  {

    if(String(Data[ARow][3]) == "" && String(Data[ARow][4]) == "" && String(Data[ARow][5]) == "" && String(Data[ARow][6]) == "" && String(Data[ARow][7]) == "" && String(Data[ARow][8]) == "" && String(Data[ARow][9]) == "" && String(Data[ARow][10]) == "" && String(Data[ARow][11]) == ""
 && String(Data[ARow][12]) == "" && String(Data[ARow][13]) == "" && String(Data[ARow][14]) == "" && String(Data[ARow][15]) == "" && String(Data[ARow][16]) == "" && String(Data[ARow][17]) == "")
    {

      Browser.msgBox(ARow + 2 + " " + "Test");
      StoreRows[ArrayRow] = ARow + 2;
      ArrayRow++;

    }


  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Insteated of

```
StoreRows[ArrayRow] = ARow + 2;
ArrayRow++;
```

Try

```
StoreRows.push(ARow + 2);
```